# Digit Occurence of a Number in Perl

Tags: perl

The question is:
Perl script that counts the number of times each digit appears in the given input. Print the total for each digit and the sum of all the totals.

The script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $str = '654768687698579870333';

if ($str =~ /(.*)[^a]+/) {

    my $substr = $1;
    my %counts;

    $counts{$_}++ for $substr =~ /./g;

    print "The count each digit appears is: \n";
    print "'$_' - $counts{$_}\n" foreach sort keys %counts;
    my $sum = 0;
    $sum += $counts{$_} foreach keys %counts;
    print "The sum of all the totals is $sum\n";    
}
```

The Output I am getting is:

```
The count each digit appears is:
'0' - 1
'3' - 2
'4' - 1
'5' - 2
'6' - 4
'7' - 4
'8' - 4
'9' - 2
The sum of all the totals is 20
```

But the output I am supposed to get is:

```
The count each digit appears is:
'0' - 1
'3' - 3
'4' - 1
'5' - 2
'6' - 4
'7' - 4
'8' - 4
'9' - 2
The sum of all the totals is 21
```

Where am I going wrong? Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the inspecting the entire string (`$str`), you inspect all but the last character of it (`$substr`).

```
if ($str =~ /(.*)[^a]+/) {
    my $substr = $1;

    my %counts;
    $counts{$_}++ for $substr =~ /./g;
```

should be

```
my %counts;
++$counts{$_} for $str =~ /[0-9]/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $numbers = "654768687698579870333";
$numbers =~ s{(\d)}{$1,}xmsg;

my %counts;
map {$counts{$_}++} split (/,/, $numbers);

print Dumper(\%counts);
```

**Output**

```
$VAR1 = {
      '6' => 4,
      '3' => 3,
      '7' => 4,
      '9' => 2,
      '8' => 4,
      '4' => 1,
      '0' => 1,
      '5' => 2
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                             

use strict;

my $str = '654768687698579870333';
my (%counts, $sum);

while ($str =~ m/(\d)/g) {

    $counts{$1}++;
    $sum++;
}

print "The count each digit appears is: \n";
print "'$_' - $counts{$_}\n" for sort keys %counts;
print "The sum of all the totals is $sum\n";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
The count each digit appears is: 
'0' - 1
'3' - 3
'4' - 1
'5' - 2
'6' - 4
'7' - 4
'8' - 4
'9' - 2
The sum of all the totals is 21
```